# Extending Django Auth User model

Tags: python, django

admin.py

```
class NetUserInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = NetUser

class UserProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    inlines = [NetUserInline, ]

admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)
```

models.py

```
class NetUser(AbstractUser):
    Net_30 = models.BooleanField(default=False)

site.register(NetUser)
```

im getting error like this.

```
django.core.management.base.CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
accounts.netuser: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
accounts.netuser: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'groups' clashes with related m2m field 'Group.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'groups'.
auth.user: Accessor for m2m field 'user_permissions' clashes with related m2m field 'Permission.user_set'. Add a related_name argument to the definition for 'user_permissions'.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Django User model is automatically part of any Django project. That is to say that the User model will create all database tables that are part of it at the same time you run `syncdb`. You have subclassed AbstractUser for your NetUser class, meaning that all the fields that are part of AbstractUser are part of NetUser as well. So, right now your database has tables such as this...

- User

  - username
  - password
  - email
  - ...
- NetUser

  - username
  - password
  - email
  - ...
  - net_30

As part of Django's user administration, database tables are created that manage what groups/permissions users have within your application(s). Right now it appears that this system is attempting to connect to both the standard User model and your NetUser model. I'd assume this is because by subclassing AbstractUser Django attempts to create all relations to that user model. At the same time, if you haven't specified that you are using a custom user model then Django will be attempting to do the same to the standard user model.

The [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#specifying-custom-user-model) states you must specify what you are using for a user model if not the default by adding `AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'Accounts.NetUser'` to your settings.py file. This tells your Django project that you are using a custom User model and not connect to the standard User model. Right now both are happening.

Furthermore, you should change `admin.site.register(User, UserProfileAdmin)` to `admin.site.register(NetUser, UserProfileAdmin)` so that your Admin backend is looking at your custom User model and not the standard Django User model.

Comment: I tried the above explanation but noe im getting error like this.

Comment: shop.cart: 'user' has a relation with model Accounts.NetUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
shop.order: 'user' has a relation with model Accounts.NetUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
accounts.address: 'user_shipping' has a relation with model Accounts.NetUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
accounts.address: 'user_billing' has a relation with model Accounts.NetUser, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
reversion.revision: 'user' has a relation with model Accounts.NetUser, which has either not been installed

Answer (score 0):

You probably forgot to set AUTH_USER_MODEL in settings.py

```
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'myapp.NetUser'
```

docs: [substituting-a-custom-user-model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model)

PS: However using some kind of [profile](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users) imho is generally less painful )